# Javascript recursive implementation of Levy C Curve

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I'm stuck on an error I can't resolve on the problem mentioned in the title.

My Algorithm looks the following:

```
function levyCCurve(x,y, len, angle, points,order){
  fx = x
  fy = y
  length = len
  alpha = angle
  it_n = order
  if(it_n > 0){
    length = length/Math.sqrt(2)

    levyCCurve(fx,fy,length,alpha+45,points, it_n - 1);
    fx = fx + (length * Math.cos((angle + 45)/180*Math.PI))
    fy = fy + (length * Math.sin((angle + 45)/180*Math.PI))
    levyCCurve(fx,fy,length,angle-45,points,it_n - 1);

  } else {
    points.push([fx,fy,fx + (length*Math.cos(angle/180*Math.PI)),fy+ (length*Math.sin(angle/180*Math.PI))])

    }

  }
```

Which is very heavily based on the implementation shown on the wikipedia page. I've had my own implementation which had an error too, and thus decided to quickly do the one shown on wikipedia, but now this one doesn't work as well.

Example: If I start the function like this `levyCCurve(500,500,100,0,pointsArray,2)` i get the following points:

[500, 500, 600, 500]

[500, 500, 550, 550]

[550, 550, 600, 500]

[500, 500, 500, 550]

[500, 550, 550, 550]

[535.3553390593273, 585.3553390593273, 570.7106781186546, 550]

Where clearly the last point is wrong and I don't get why, would be awesome if someone could point out where I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a Problem with variable scope, which is pretty tough if you're new to javascript, like me.

It works when you define the variables at the beginning of the method with `let` such that they are only defined in the actual call.